# Creating development builds on iPhone for use by external tester(s)

Tags: iphone, xcode

How do you build an development iPhone app that can run on arbitrary iPhones you do not have in-hand?  I have no iPhone, personally and wish to create a build that I can distribute to a small group of beta testers?

I have a signing cert, but get the dreaded error:

> "Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it."

tone

Comment: If you have learned that the error is "dreaded", surely there are some resources available that tell you how to deal with it?

Comment: You would have to use Testflight or ad hoc distribution. But if you don't have a physical device how can you be sure that your app is even working? The simulator is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, you need a paid developer account. (99$)
2. Use a TestFlight app.